# clicking on dynamically loaded div to show another div

Tags: jquery

i have this jQuery code below:

```
$.each(data.direct, function (filelist, direc) {
                $('#magazines-list').append ( $('<li>').append ('<p>'+ direc.slice(47) + '</p>') );
            });
```

then this

```
$("body").delegate("#magazines-list li p",'click', function () {
    $('#magazine-show').fadeIn(500);
    $('#magazine-show').css({width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height()});
    $('#magazine-show').append( '<p class="magazine-show-caption">' + $(this).text() + '</p>');
});
```

the problem is that when i click on a '`#magazines-list li p`', the method is triggered twice, thus I'm getting the caption twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$("#magazines-list").on("click","li > p", function () {
    $('#magazine-show').fadeIn(500);
    $('#magazine-show').css({width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height()});
    $('#magazine-show').append( '<p class="magazine-show-caption">' + $(this).text() + '</p>');
});
```

- Use `on` in place of `delegate`
- Here, `$("#magazines-list")` is the parent wrapper.
- The function above is invoked when any `p` inside the parent wrapper is clicked.